# How can I salvage a roll of water-damaged film?

Tags: film, developing

Advice needed from analogue folk, please. I have a roll of exposed 120 Ilford FP4 (I think) that somehow became wet, probably from condensation. The backing paper has now stuck firmly to the emulsion. I'm thinking of perhaps soaking the roll in water for a few hours; then attempting to unroll the film. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a veteran of the photofinishing industry, receiving wet film or film that had been wet was not uncommon. Usually rolls in clothing that went through the washing machine and/or  boat or swimming pool accidents. We would soak them for about 8 hours in plain water from the sink and then attempt to unroll in the darkroom. Our success rate was usually good. Sometimes the film strongly adheres to itself or paper backing. We would re-soak in PhotoFlow or we would add a few drops of liquid dishwashing detergent to the water.  Best of luck on recovering this film.

Comment: You say, "We would soak them for about 8 hours." Could you be a bit specific about exactly *in what solution* you were soaking?

Comment: Thank you!  Most helpful.  I'll give soaking the film a go.

Answer (score 4):

I taught photography in college for 29 years and have "seen it all". We would put the film in a light-tight processing tank and fill it with plain water at 68-72°F (20-22°C) and agitate the tank for a minute or so. Pour out the water and pour-in fresh water a few times. We would do a water exchange/agitation cycle three or four more times during the first hour, and then in a film processing room check to feel if anything was happening. If needed, change the water and agitate one more time and let it sit. If no success after three hours, we would transfer the roll to a Photo-Flo bath prepared as for film processing, and check on it every half hour. If still unsuccessful after two hours, we would slowly increase the Photo-Flo bath temperature to about 90-110°F (32-43°C).

Comment: Wouldn't heating FP4 to 110F cause reticulation and irreversible damage of the gelatin layer?

Comment: I'll make sure the water is the temperature you recommend. For us Europeans, that's 20-22°C initially rising to 32-43°C if needed. Thank you.

Comment: MirekE - Reticulating commercially available film manufactured since the early 1960s is very difficult to achieve with temperature. Before then, some films with a high silver content and thicker less stable emulsion, would reticulate at about 160F or even higher to almost boiling.